# Scraping a webpage content which is getting loaded by AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs, watir

I have a code snippet which is scraping the content of a webpage. The content on webpage is getting loaded by AJAX. I'm scraping the data in a loop, and every time it ends up with one of the following errors:

```
1. Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:35216  
2. could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)  
3. Net::ReadTimeout
```

Code:

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
browser = nil
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, :http_client => client 
browser.window.maximize
browser.goto "some URL"
final_url = URI.parse(browser.url) 
#Sleep for 35 seconds, expecting data to get rendered by ajax
sleep(35)
unless pagecheck.css('li.some-class').empty?
    sleep(25)
end
```

Comment: Do you have the option to use a different driver? PhantomJS is deprecated. Chrome in headless mode provides similar functionality.